# Does the Rails after_filter get executed before or after Mocha's automatic call to unstub?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-mocha

My controller class inherits from ActionController::Base.

I am using rails 2 and ruby 1.9.3.

I am using Mocha to stub out calls to Perforce so my tests are not dependent on connections to perforce.

In my rails after_filter, I call one of my stubbed methods, hoping that it has not yet been unstubbed. In the normal application, it releases the Perforce connections.

I get this error message:

> unexpected invocation: Api::BuildsController.perforce_service()

The method `perforce_service` is the method I stubbed out. I suspect that it is being called after it has already been unstubbed by Mocha, but I am not sure. When is the Mocha unstubbing done relative to the after_filter? How should I architect this?

When I try manually stubbing and unstubbing an object's method in pry, the method is still callable after I call unstub, which is not what I expect. I expect that unstub will restore the original method, or if it had no original method, to restore it to a state of being an undefined method. What does it really do?

NOTE:

Mocha documentation says to put this in test_helper.rb if you use rails:

```
require 'mocha/mini_test'
```

However, if I add this to my Gemfile and run bundle install:

```
gem 'mocha/mini_test'
```

then I get an error:

```
Could not find gem 'mocha/mini_test (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should really update your stack to versions released this decade.

Comment: We are in the midst of migrating from Rails 2 to Rails 4 and from Ruby 1.8.6 to 1.9.3. It will take awhile.